# Reactivity for Vue props that are objects

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that has a prop called `value` (used for `v-model`) and the type of the prop is an object. Here is an example value of the prop `value`:

```
{type: "column": {value: {column: "col1", anotherattr: "test"}}}
```

However; if I pass the following value to the component, it causes reactivity problems since `anotherattr` is not defined here:

```
{type: "column": {value: {column: "col1"}}}
```

I want the component to be able to validate the schema and make the attributes reactive automatically because `anotherattr` is actually an optional property.

What's the suggested approach here? I thought about using `validator` but it looked like an anti-pattern since it's used for validation. Is there any practical approach to this problem? (Maybe Typescript be helpful?)

Comment: I added ES6 and Typescript tags because if there is a novel solution that I can use, I can just create a watcher for value and pass it to that custom TS or ES6 library. I'm also OK with the third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

With Typescript you could do something like this:

```
export class YourProp {
    constructor(
        public value: YourValue
    )
}

export class YourValue {
    constructor (
        public columnName: String,
        public anotherAttr: String = "default" // give it a default value since its optional
)
```

And then don't handle the prop as an Object but as an instance of YourProp.